# Selecting From a MySQL Table where multiple conditions (rows) are found in a different table

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli, joomla3.2

I am creating a job search engine, which will support advanced search.

[image]

What I want to do is allow someone to search for "sample" and then set payment type to "hour" as a criteria. This would then only show the Sample technical job.

The code below works and outputs the expected result

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tnqj3_content LEFT JOIN tnqj3_fieldsattach_values ON tnqj3_fieldsattach_values.articleid = tnqj3_content.id WHERE tnqj3_content.title LIKE '%$q_keywords%' AND tnqj3_fieldsattach_values.value='hour'
```

However I want to add multiple criteria so they can also request that the pay rate is "10" (id=4). When I add "OR" on the the end of the statement it gets the result twice

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tnqj3_content LEFT JOIN tnqj3_fieldsattach_values ON tnqj3_fieldsattach_values.articleid = tnqj3_content.id WHERE tnqj3_content.title LIKE '%$q_keywords%' AND tnqj3_fieldsattach_values.value='hour' OR tnqj3_fieldsattach_values.value='10'
```

If I change OR to AND then no result is found. How can I set it so it fetches the row once if both criteria are found?

For context this is the code: (Ps. it is all being sanitized):

```
// Get search paramaters
$q_keywords = $_GET['q_keywords'];

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tnqj3_content LEFT JOIN tnqj3_fieldsattach_values ON tnqj3_fieldsattach_values.articleid = tnqj3_content.id WHERE tnqj3_content.title LIKE '%$q_keywords%' AND tnqj3_fieldsattach_values.value='hour' OR tnqj3_fieldsattach_values.value='10' ");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
      echo "<div class='search-result'><a href='/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=" . $row['id'] . "' class='search-result-title'>" . $row['title'] . "</a>" . $row['introtext'];

      echo "</div>";
  }
```

Comment: In your query, you are requesting all columns from both tables (tnqj3_content and tnqj3_fieldsattach_values). Do you need all columns, or just the columns from tnqj3_content? If just the limited number of columns then use  `SELECT DISTINCT tnqj3_content.*`

Comment: I've purely changed it to that so there is slightly less to look at one here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tnqj3_content 
JOIN (
  SELECT articleid FROM tnqj3_fieldsattach_values
  GROUP BY articleid
  HAVING SUM(
    CASE value
     WHEN 'hour' THEN 1
     WHEN '10' THEN 1
     ELSE 0
    END 
    ) = 2
  ) t
ON t.articleid = tnqj3_content.id 
WHERE tnqj3_content.title LIKE '%$q_keywords%'
```

Here you have to add each of your user provided filters in the `CASE` clause of sql AND also give the count of your filters to compare with the `SUM`, so in my answer I have used `2` as I have 2 filters, one is 'hour' and second is '10.

Comment: I've changed it to what you suggested but getting the same result (OR gives double AND gives nothing)
The new code:::

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tnqj3_content LEFT JOIN tnqj3_fieldsattach_values ON tnqj3_fieldsattach_values.articleid = tnqj3_content.id WHERE tnqj3_content.title LIKE '%$q_keywords%' AND (tnqj3_fieldsattach_values.value='hour' OR tnqj3_fieldsattach_values.value='10')");

Comment: @tim.baker Based on your comment, I have updated my answer using another approach.

Comment: @tim.baker Previous query is totally incorrect. I am updating my answer.

Comment: Just in case, you want to take a look at the old query, it is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/ec173e60-bbe4-40d6-aba8-d96e49d01c12/view-source).